# PushRow and UISplitViewController navigation

Tags: ios, swift3, eureka-forms

I am working on a `UISplitViewController` subclass that has a `UINavigationController` as master viewcontroller (the reason for this is that I need the navigation bar). The `UINavigationController` has a `FormViewController` subclass as rootViewController. In the form I am using a `PushRow` to show a list of selectable options. The problem is that when I tap the `PushRow` in a regular-width environment the `SelectorViewController` is pushed in the master navigation stack. I would like to see the `SelectorViewController` showed as a `UISplitViewController` detail instead.

I created a `DummyNavigationController` that looks like this:

```
class DummyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func targetViewController(forAction action: Selector, sender: Any?) -> UIViewController? {
        if let parent = parent as? UISplitViewController {
            return parent.isCollapsed ? self : parent
        }
        return self
    }

}
```

Using this as navigation controller for the `FormViewController` I am able to see the `SelectorViewController` on the detail but I don't like this approach.

Is there anything else that I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a very specific answer but I lack the reputation to comment.

You can embed only one side of the SplitViewController in a UINavigationController instead of the whole SplitViewController, this way when you segue to the SelectorViewController it will only show it on one side of the SplitViewController.

[image]

Comment: I didn't embed the entire `SplitViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.. just the master.